# in quotient space, If you do not tell me how the equivalence relation is How to address these problems?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

the problem is 
Let A = {1/n : n ∈ N} and π : I → I/A be the projection map. Let
G = [0, 1/2] ∪ {1}. Show that G is a saturated nbd of 0, but π(G) is not
a nbd of π(0).

The relationship here would be the elements of G that are in A?
Any suggestion or clue

Comment: What does "nbd" mean?

Comment: What does the title question mean? How to address which problems? Is it not the question "the problem is"?

Comment: I think he/she does not understand which is the equivalence relation that leads to the quotient map.

Comment: What is $I$? This question could be made clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A=\{1/n : n \in \mathbb{Z}_+ \},$ $I=[0,1].$ The space $I/A$ is the quotient space that collapses the set $A$ in a single point.
Let $a \in I/A$ be the point in which $A$ is collapsed. Then
$$ I/A = \{a \} \cup \{ \{x \} : x \in I, x \neq 1/n \text{ for }n \in \mathbb{Z}_+\}.$$

Let $p:I \to I/A$ be the quotient map. Let $G=[0,1/2]\cup \{1\}.$ To show that $G$ is saturated, we must show it is the complete inverse image of a subset of $I/A.$ For this, try 
$$B=\{a\}\cup\{\{x\}: x \in I, x \neq 1/n \text{ for }n \in \mathbb{Z}_+, 0 \leq x < 1/2\}.$$
Then $B \subset I/A$ and $G=p^{-1}(B).$

To show that $\pi(G)$ is not a neighborhood of $\pi(0),$ note that $p(G)=p(p^{-1}(B))=B$ ($p$ is surjective), but $B$ is not open in $I/A$ since $\pi^{-1}(G)$ is not open in $I.$ (Definition of quotient topology.)

Note that a quotient map maps saturated *open* sets of $I$ to open sets of $Y,$ but this is not the case since $G$ is not open in $I.$

Comment: how did you know that was the quotient, what equivalence relationship did you have?

That's what I do not understand, I do not know how to take the equivalence relation

Comment: Since you have the quotient $I/A$ where $A \subset I,$ the equivalente relation is given by $a \sim b$ if $a,b \in A,$ and if $x \notin A,$ then $x$ is related only to itself.